# When using 7zip from the command line, how can I have 7zip archive creation overwrite the existing archive?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

Currently it updates the archive where as I would like the whole thing overwritten. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the command you are currently using? Also explain what you mean by "updates the archive", isn't the new archive the same thing you want?

Comment: https://7ziphelp.com/7zip-command-line. If it's not an option 7zip offers, simply delete existing first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with only 7zip. [Add command](https://7-zip.opensource.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm) doesn't have overwrite mode, only extract command does (`-aoa`).

You can simply delete the file with a one-liner in cmd:

```
del output.7z && 7za a -t7z output.7z *.txt
```

Use `if exist` if you really need to make sure it "overwrites" a file, for some reason.

Comment: Strange it's not an option, but thanks for the solution!